# Check if account is local using SID or LUID

Tags: c, winapi, wmi, sid

The `Win32_Account` class from WMI has a `LocalAccount` boolean property. Unfortunately, the `SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA` structure obtained by calling `LsaGetLogonSessionData` does not. What's the best way to verify if an account is local as in WMI, having the *security identifier* SID and the *logon identifier* LUID?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `UserName` or `Upn` fields in the information output from `LsaGetLogonSessionData`?  This might be a qualified user-name, with either a machine name or a domain as the first part of the string which could help you to determine the location of the account.

Comment: Currently I am comparing `LogonDomain` from the same structure with the computer name from `GetComputerNameEx`. Seems to work, but I don't know if it's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: I don't see why that would not work. Only problem is whether or not each of the data items you compare is guaranteed to be in canonical form, or if there are semantically-equivalent but non-identical values that might pop up. Knowing the machine-name-based roots of Windows, I personally doubt it.  You could try asking on the LSA-specific MSDN forums in case some MVP has a better idea.